# How to filter on date in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wrote the following code, trying to filter on dates using DRF:

```
class FixtureFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.DateFilter('date__date', lookup_expr='exact')
    class Meta:
        model = Fixture
        fields = ['date']

class FixtureViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = FixtureSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_class = FixtureFilter
```

When I make a call to the API like `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/fixtures?date=2021-11-29` it returns me more than 1 object whereas it should just return 1 object.

How do I implement this properly?

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one object with provided date?

Comment: @funnydman Yup, only got 1 object with that that in my database

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must add `filter_backends` field to `FixtureViewSet` to get it working, how documentation [describes](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#quickstart). Also, don't forget to update `INSTALLED_APPS` with django_filter as well. The corrected version would be:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filter

class FixtureFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.DateFilter('date', lookup_expr='exact')

    class Meta:
        model = Fixture
        fields = ['date']

class FixtureViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = FixtureSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = FixtureFilter
```